# Extract the "real" scientific exponent from a double in C#

Tags: c#, floating-point, ieee-754

In C#, IEEE-754 numbers (in this case `System.Double`) can be declared in Base 10 scientific notation; for example: [1.234e+9](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1.234e%2B9) (1234000000), but the Base 2 floating point representation of these values is often just a close approximation due to the limitations of how floating point numbers are stored. With respect, consider the following table:

| Scientific Notation | IEEE-754 Approximation |
| --- | --- |
| 1e-1 | 0.10000000000000001 |
| 1e-2 | 0.01 |
| 1e-3 | 0.001 |
| 1e-4 | 0.0001 |
| 1e-5 | 1.0000000000000001E-05 |
| 1e-6 | 9.9999999999999995E-07 |
| 1e-7 | 9.9999999999999995E-08 |
| 1e-8 | 1E-8 |
| 1e-9 | 1.0000000000000001E-09 |
| 1e-10 | 1E-10 |

*Ignore the fact that the IEEE-754 approximations are all formatted differently. These values were all taken directly from a debugger. It's useful to see them in different forms as it helps explain the problem.*

What I want to do is extract the exponent from the number. So far I have this function:

```cs
private static int GetScientificExponent(double value)
{
    return (int)double.Floor(double.Log10(double.Abs(value)));
}
```

Combining this with the table of results above, we can determine the scientific exponent for each case:

| Scientific Notation | IEEE-754 Approximation | Scientific Exponent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1e-1 | 0.10000000000000001 | -1 |
| 1e-2 | 0.01 | -2 |
| 1e-3 | 0.001 | -3 |
| 1e-4 | 0.0001 | -4 |
| 1e-5 | 1.0000000000000001E-05 | -5 |
| 1e-6 | 9.9999999999999995E-07 | -6 |
| 1e-7 | 9.9999999999999995E-08 | -7 |
| 1e-8 | 1E-8 | -8 |
| 1e-9 | 1.0000000000000001E-09 | -9 |
| 1e-10 | 1E-10 | -10 |

The scientific exponents match the **Scientific Notation** for every case, but they do not match the **IEEE-754 Approximation** for every case, as I have illustrated in this table. Note the outliers, highlighted in bold:

| Scientific Notation | IEEE-754 Representation | Scientific Exponent | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1e-1 | 0.10000000000000001 | -1 | OK |
| 1e-2 | 0.01 | -2 | OK |
| 1e-3 | 0.001 | -3 | OK |
| 1e-4 | 0.0001 | -4 | OK |
| 1e-5 | 1.0000000000000001E-05 | -5 | OK |
| **1e-6** | **9.9999999999999995E-07** | **-6** | **E-6 vs. E-7** |
| **1e-7** | **9.9999999999999995E-08** | **-7** | **E-7 vs. E-8** |
| 1e-8 | 1E-8 | -8 | OK |
| 1e-9 | 1.0000000000000001E-09 | -9 | OK |
| 1e-10 | 1E-10 | -10 | OK |

This seems reasonable considering that if you represent these numbers in their *actual* form, rather than relying on .NET's underlying rounding mechanisms (Dragon4 or so I'm led to believe), then you end up with this:

| Scientific Notation | Base 10 Representation | IEEE-754 Approximation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1e-6 | 0.000001 | 0.000000999999999999999954748111825886258685613938723690807819366455078125 |

Notably, in Base 10 the `1` is in the 6th position after the decimal point, whereas in the IEEE-754 approximation, the `9` is in the 7th position, hence -6 vs. -7...that makes sense.

### Question

Given my `GetScientificExponent` function, is it possible to obtain the exponent from the approximation? For example; `1e-2` should return `-2` as it does now, but `1e-6` should return `-7` because that's the exponent of the approximate value?

For completeness, here's the code I'm using to test:

```cs
using static System.Double;

internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] values = { 3e-1, 1e-1, 1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5, 1e-6, 1e-7, 1e-8, 1e-9, 1e-10 };

        foreach (double value in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"|{value:F10}|{GetScientificExponent(value)}|");
        }
    }

    private static int GetScientificExponent(double value)
    {
        return (int)Floor(Log10(Abs(value)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's possible (it has to be, because `double.ToString()` can print the exponent you're after). However, the code is complex (it's Dragon4 as you noted) and it seems to be internal, and only referenced from the code which formats doubles as strings (ultimately [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Number.Dragon4.cs,115), called from [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Number.Formatting.cs,631).

Comment: Honestly, the easiest (and most accurate) route is going to be to format as a string (using `.ToString("G17")`), then parse the result.

Comment: If you want a more satisfying answer, head over to #allow-unsafe-blocks on the [C# discord](https://discord.com/servers/c-143867839282020352) -- a bunch of compiler/runtime folks hang out there, including Tanner Gooding who'll be able to definitively answer this

Comment: Thanks @canton7. I've tweeted a link to them.

Comment: Who did you tweet? That discord channel is by far the best place to ask these sorts of questions

Comment: @canton7 - https://twitter.com/MrMatthewLayton/status/1659180334406148096?s=20

Comment: @Matthew Layton, Do you want this to work for all finite `double`?  Including tiny values near  `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()`?  Note `GetScientificExponent(0.0)` is a problem.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes any finite double. Apologies this code is incomplete. For 0, -0, 1 or -1 it should return 0, and for NaN or infinity it should throw an exception. I’ll update the code shortly.

Comment: A really nice question. I'd just comment that what you mean for "IEEE754 approximation" is always rounded in your table even if you don't print that. For example, 0.01 is internally 0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375. Seems your printing functions hide this. I've used Python `'%.70f' % 0.01` for the full view.

Answer (score 2):

An approach is to let your library's `double` to *text* routines to do the higher precision math needed.  Using user `double` math is insufficient/inconvenient.

The "trick" is to print to a high enough precision such that values near a power-of-10 do not cause the exponent to change when rounding and then simply parse for the exponent.

Below is C code to illustrate.

In particular, printing to 17 (`DBL_DECIMAL_DIG`) significant digits was insufficient in the case of `1e-79`.  Instead code prints `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG + 1` significant decimal digits.  There is little to lose using more digits, up to a point.  I recommend `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG + 3`.  Beyond that, libraries need not print correct digits and maintain [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) compliance.

Sample code

```
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int GetScientificExponent(double value) {
  return (int) floor(log10(fabs(value)));
}

// 0.0, infinity and NAN return INT_MIN.  Adjust as desired.
int GetScientificExponent_alt1(double value) {
  #define PREC ((DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1) + 1 /* or + 3 */)
  if (isfinite(value)) {
    //       -   d   .         ddddd           e   -  eee \0
    char buf[1 + 1 + 1 + PREC + 1 + 1 + 5 + 1];
    sprintf(buf, "%.*e", PREC, value);
    printf("<%-30s>", buf);
    // Look for the exponent start
    const char *e = strchr(buf, 'e');
    if (e) {
      return atoi(e + 1);
    }
  }
  return INT_MIN;
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void test1(double x) {
  printf("%30.*e %4d %4d\n", //
      DBL_DECIMAL_DIG * 3 / 2, x,
      GetScientificExponent_alt1(x), GetScientificExponent(x));
}

void test3(int power10) {
  double x = pow(10.0, power10);
  //test1(nextafter(x, +INFINITY));
  test1(x);
  //test1(nextafter(x, -INFINITY));
  //puts("");
}

int main() {
  for (int power10 = 0; power10 <= DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - DBL_MIN_10_EXP; power10++) {
    test3(-power10);
  }
}
```

Output

```
<1.00000000000000000e+00       >1.0000000000000000000000000e+00    0    0
<1.00000000000000006e-01       >1.0000000000000000555111512e-01   -1   -1
<1.00000000000000002e-02       >1.0000000000000000208166817e-02   -2   -2
<1.00000000000000002e-03       >1.0000000000000000208166817e-03   -3   -3
<1.00000000000000005e-04       >1.0000000000000000479217360e-04   -4   -4
<1.00000000000000008e-05       >1.0000000000000000818030539e-05   -5   -5
<9.99999999999999955e-07       >9.9999999999999995474811183e-07   -7   -6
<9.99999999999999955e-08       >9.9999999999999995474811183e-08   -8   -7
<1.00000000000000002e-08       >1.0000000000000000209225608e-08   -8   -8
<1.00000000000000006e-09       >1.0000000000000000622815915e-09   -9   -9
<1.00000000000000004e-10       >1.0000000000000000364321973e-10  -10  -10
<9.99999999999999939e-12       >9.9999999999999993949696928e-12  -12  -11
<9.99999999999999980e-13       >9.9999999999999997988664763e-13  -13  -12
<1.00000000000000003e-13       >1.0000000000000000303737456e-13  -13  -13
<9.99999999999999999e-15       >9.9999999999999999881930935e-15  -15  -14
<1.00000000000000008e-15       >1.0000000000000000777053999e-15  -15  -15
<9.99999999999999979e-17       >9.9999999999999997909778672e-17  -17  -16
<1.00000000000000007e-17       >1.0000000000000000715424241e-17  -17  -17
<1.00000000000000007e-18       >1.0000000000000000715424241e-18  -18  -18
<9.99999999999999975e-20       >9.9999999999999997524592684e-20  -20  -19
<9.99999999999999945e-21       >9.9999999999999994515327145e-21  -21  -20
<9.99999999999999908e-22       >9.9999999999999990753745223e-22  -22  -21
<1.00000000000000005e-22       >1.0000000000000000485967743e-22  -22  -22
<9.99999999999999960e-24       >9.9999999999999996043469801e-24  -24  -23
<9.99999999999999924e-25       >9.9999999999999992370049955e-25  -25  -24
<1.00000000000000004e-25       >1.0000000000000000384948697e-25  -25  -25
<1.00000000000000004e-26       >1.0000000000000000384948697e-26  -26  -26
<1.00000000000000004e-27       >1.0000000000000000384948697e-27  -27  -27
<9.99999999999999971e-29       >9.9999999999999997123254346e-29  -29  -28
<9.99999999999999943e-30       >9.9999999999999994320657418e-30  -30  -29
<1.00000000000000008e-30       >1.0000000000000000833364206e-30  -30  -30
...
<9.99999999999999958e-76       >9.9999999999999995765001370e-76  -76  -75
<9.99999999999999927e-77       >9.9999999999999992696817954e-77  -77  -76
<9.99999999999999927e-78       >9.9999999999999992696817954e-78  -78  -77
<9.99999999999999999e-79       >9.9999999999999999887872835e-79  -79  -78
<9.99999999999999999e-80       >9.9999999999999999887872835e-80  -80  -79
<9.99999999999999961e-81       >9.9999999999999996142531751e-81  -81  -80
<9.99999999999999961e-82       >9.9999999999999996142531751e-82  -82  -81
<9.99999999999999961e-83       >9.9999999999999996142531751e-83  -83  -82
...
<9.99999983659714433e-317      >9.9999998365971443346061921e-317 -317 -317
<1.00000023069253735e-317      >1.0000002306925373540838913e-317 -317 -317
<9.99998748495599830e-319      >9.9999874849559983034425877e-319 -319 -319
<9.99988867182683005e-320      >9.9998886718268300541337524e-320 -320 -320
<9.99988867182683005e-321      >9.9998886718268300541337524e-321 -321 -321
<9.98012604599318019e-322      >9.9801260459931801923666896e-322 -322 -322
<9.88131291682493088e-323      >9.8813129168249308835313759e-323 -323 -323
<9.88131291682493088e-324      >9.8813129168249308835313759e-324 -324 -324
<0.00000000000000000e+00       >0.0000000000000000000000000e+00    0 -2147483648
```

---

**Alternative 2**

Use high precision math.  When `long double` precision exceeds `double` by at least 10 bits, OP's original approach works well too.

```
// Needs work for 0.0, infinity, NAN
private static int GetScientificExponent_alt2(double value) {
    long double dv = value;
    return (int)floor(log10(abs(dv)));
}
```

Of course, if `long double` is not extra precise, this has the same troubles as OP's original.